# Limits on frequency generation using nonlinear device + resonator cavity

Tags: rf, microwave

I recently saw a schematic of an RF device which supposedly could generate a ~1GHz sine waveform via a 50MHz square wave run through a diode and fed into a cavity resonator.

What I'm curious about is if this degree of frequency multiplication is even possible.

In general, when would you want to design an oscillator at the target frequency versus when would you want to use some form of frequency multiplier + bandpass filter?

It seems easier to generate a stable 50MHz square wave than a 1GHz sine wave but there must be some down side.

Comment: How sharp are the original edges?   In a theoretical square wave, there is overtone energy to infinite frequency, but of course there is no such thing as a square wave in reality, only band limited approximations.  Build a circuit right, and non-linearity can "sharpen" an edge, and then resonance reinforce an overtone...

Answer (score 1):

Pin Diodes work well up into the GHz range as switches or harmonic devices from subharmonic pulses rich with harmonics.

So I don’t see the diode being a limitation.  The pulse width must be less than the period to contain as much energy as possible.